# Control is not exiting the loop even though the conditions met?

Tags: java

The control is not exiting the loop even though conditions are met. Like if the `recipientEmailAddressList` size is > 1 and even though the `foundEmail` is true for the first try itself it's not exiting the loop. What is wrong in this do while loop?
Please tell me what is wrong in the below code.

```
do {
                if(reTry>=1){
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                }
                response = RestAssured.given().accept("application/json").get(url);
                String responseBody = response.asString();
                JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseBody);
                List<String> recipientEmailAddressList = jsonPath.get("recipientEmail");
                System.out.println("receipeinet email list size "+recipientEmailAddressList.size());
                for (int i=0;i<recipientEmailAddressList.size();i++) {
                if(recipientEmailAddressList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(studentEmail)){                                    
                    System.out.println(recipientEmailAddressList.get(i));
                    List<Object> rawRequest = jsonPath.get("rawRequest");
                    JsonPath rawRequestJsonPath = new JsonPath(rawRequest.get(0).toString());
                    String claimURL=rawRequestJsonPath.getString("parameters.claim_url");
                    NewTempData.storedata(6, 1, claimURL);
                    System.out.println("Credential Claim URL "+claimURL);
                    foundEmail = true;
                }else{
                    foundEmail = false;
                }
                }
                reTry++;
            } while (reTry < 30 &!foundEmail);
            if(foundEmail){
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: For the very first time i tried with && only but when the left hand condition is true(!foundEmail) when i got the response its not exiting where as loop continued. so tried with & but this alos doesnt fix the issue.

Comment: @CraigR8806 A single `&` *does* denote a comparison when the operands are boolean, it just does not shortcut when the left hand side is `false`. I.e. the right hand side of `false & 2>1` is evaluated, while this is not the case in `false && 2>1`

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, use && instead of &.

The other thing, is that your for loop for going through the list of emails, will continue even if you do find the email. Basically, foundEmail is set to true, and then you go on to the next email and set it back to false.
Either, place "break;" or "return true;" after "foundEmail = true"

Also, instead of looping through the email list yourself, you can use recipientEmailAddressList.contains(studentEmail)